# Automatically copy new folder contents to another folder after upload

Tags: image-processing, file-upload, copy

Is there any way a new image upload from a PHP form sent to `directory a` can be copied to `directory b` **after** it has been uploaded? In this case it's not possible to alter the upload path itself or copy it during upload so I'm looking for some kind of automatic replication of new directory contents into another directory after the file has been uploaded.

Is there an automated service/script that can move the content of one directory on our server to another directory? We upload files to `www.mysite.com/upload/thumb` for example but need them to be moved automatically to `www.mysite.com/cs/upload/thumb` - is this possible without running a move_uploaded_file PHP script (I would prefer it to be done by the server because we use the same page for many different landing page functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you look for `copy` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your problem... A user uploaded img1.jpg and this has been saved in directory A. If you want to copy that image to directoy B, just run `copy("/A/img1.php","/B/img1.php");`... deleting the img1.jpg from A can be done this way: `unlink("/A/img1.png");`

Comment: The problem is that particular page is used for the main landing page for new users following sign-up as well as the page they see after an image has been added to their user page. I think running the script again and again would waste resources and cause errors?

Comment: I have a possibly simpler idea for this, I'll create a new question.

Comment: you must run this once per image... but I don't have an idea how to avoid this if your upload script saves the image to directory A...

Comment: and don't undervalue the memory use... It depends on your image size so it can be very high on large images...

Comment: Fortunately this has been sorted now by correcting the original upload path which was previous encrypted. Thanks for all your suggestions.